# Porting JME to WebGL

Tags: java, gwt, webgl

Is it possible to port an existing graphics engine like [jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/) to something like [GwtGL](http://code.google.com/p/gwtgl/) or [gwt-g3d](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-g3d/)? Is it only to replace native OpenGL calls to WebGL calls or there's more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will likely be more to it than that. Take a look at [this page](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html); if JME makes use of any classes or methods not listed there then you'll need to find a workaround.

Good luck, though! Sounds like a cool project.